# Heroku authorization header missing

Tags: react-native, go, heroku, cors

I have a golang api service deployed in heroku. I am calling the api from the react native iOS application, using axios. The problem is authorization header goes missing in heroku even though I have verified that I am sending the authorization header using reactotron.

Client side:

```
const {data} = await axios.get(url, {
  headers: {
     Authorization: `Basic ${token}`,
  },
});
```

Server side log:

```
time="2020-06-27T00:41:06Z" level=info msg=Header name=Accept value="application/json, text/plain, */*"
2020-06-27T00:41:06.875881+00:00 app[web.1]: time="2020-06-27T00:41:06Z" level=info msg=Header name=Accept-Encoding value="gzip, deflate, br"
2020-06-27T00:41:06.875885+00:00 app[web.1]: time="2020-06-27T00:41:06Z" level=info msg=Header name=Connection value=close
2020-06-27T00:41:06.875912+00:00 app[web.1]: time="2020-06-27T00:41:06Z" level=info msg=Header name=X-Forwarded-For value=some ip address
2020-06-27T00:41:06.875969+00:00 app[web.1]: time="2020-06-27T00:41:06Z" level=info msg=Header name=X-Forwarded-Proto value=https
2020-06-27T00:41:06.875970+00:00 app[web.1]: time="2020-06-27T00:41:06Z" level=info msg=Header name=Connect-Time value=1
2020-06-27T00:41:06.875994+00:00 app[web.1]: time="2020-06-27T00:41:06Z" level=info msg=Header name=Accept-Language value=en-us
2020-06-27T00:41:06.876042+00:00 app[web.1]: time="2020-06-27T00:41:06Z" level=info msg=Header name=X-Request-Start value=1593218466874
2020-06-27T00:41:06.876047+00:00 app[web.1]: time="2020-06-27T00:41:06Z" level=info msg=Header name=Total-Route-Time value=0
2020-06-27T00:41:06.876081+00:00 app[web.1]: time="2020-06-27T00:41:06Z" level=info msg=Header name=User-Agent value="app/1 CFNetwork/1126 Darwin/19.5.0"
2020-06-27T00:41:06.876106+00:00 app[web.1]: time="2020-06-27T00:41:06Z" level=info msg=Header name=X-Request-Id value=some id
2020-06-27T00:41:06.876146+00:00 app[web.1]: time="2020-06-27T00:41:06Z" level=info msg=Header name=X-Forwarded-Port value=443
2020-06-27T00:41:06.876150+00:00 app[web.1]: time="2020-06-27T00:41:06Z" level=info msg=Header name=Via value="1.1 vegur"
```

Interesting part is I can successfully call the endpoint via Postman. The code also works perfectly with the local api service. My first assumption was CORS issue, so I added all headers like this:

```
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE")
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept, Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization")
```

where w is http.ResponseWriter. They didn't help. Authorization header is MISSING! If I send 'X-Authorization', it works fine. My guess is heroku is the problem.

Does anyone have a pointer how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

wow. I found the solution.

https://herokuapp.com//api/something drops authorization header.
https://herokuapp.com/api/something doesn't drop the header.

double slashes causing headers to drop..